# Arranging data into lists from url

Tags: urllib2, urllib, python-3.5

The following code is written in python 2.  How can I write it in python 3? thanks

```
import urllib2
import sys

#read data from uci data repository
target_url = ("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/undocumented/connectionist-bench/sonar/sonar.all-data")

data = urllib2.urlopen(target_url)

#arrange data into list for labels and list of lists for attributes
xList = []
labels = []
for line in data:
#split on comma
    row = line.strip().split(",")
    xList.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library of Python 3.

```
import requests
data = requests.get("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/undocumented/connectionist-bench/sonar/sonar.all-data").text
for line in data.split('\n'):
    row = line.strip().split(",")
    xList.append(row)
```